# Creating Singleton CacheManager in Asp.Net Core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-5.0, memorycache

I am trying to create `Singleton` CacheManager class that has dependency on `IMemoryCache`.

```
public class CacheManager:ICacheManager
{
   private readonly IMemoryCache _cache;
   
   public CacheManager(IMemoryCache cache)
   {
     _cache = cache;
   }
   
   public void LoadCache(MyData data)
   {
        // load cache here at startup from DB
   }

}
```

I also have a `Scoped` service that retrives data from the database

```
public class LookupService:ILookupService
{
   private readonly MyDatabaseContext _dbContext;
   
   public class LookupService(MyDatabaseContext dbContext)
   {
      _dbContext = dbContext;
   }
  
  public void Dispose()
  {
     //Dispose DBContext here
  }
  
   // some async methods that returns lookup collection    
}
```

Register these services in Startup.cs

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // EF
        services.AddDbContext<MyDatabaseContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        // domain services            
        services.AddScoped<ILookupService, LookupService>();
        
        services.AddMemoryCache();
        
        // singleton
        services.AddSingleton<CacheManager>(sp=> 
        { 
            using(var scope = sp.CreateScope())
            {
                using (var service = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<ILookupService>())
                {
                    how do i create cacheManager instance by injecting IMemoryCache and also register callback function
                }
            }
        });                 
    }
```

`ILookupService` is registered as `Scoped` service becuase it has dependency on DBContext which is also (by default) registered with `Scoped` lifetime. I do not want to change lifetime of these services.

However I want CacheManager to be registered as `Singleton`, that means I cannot inject `ILookupService` as dependency into CacheManager.

So here is my possible solution to create & register singleton instance of CacheManager

```
        services.AddSingleton<CacheManager>(sp=> 
        { 
            using(var scope = sp.CreateScope())
            {
                using (var lookupService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<ILookupService>())
                {
                    var cache = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<IMemoryCache>();
                    var manger =  new CacheManager(cache);
                    manger.LoadCache(lookupService.GetData());
                    return manger;
                }
            }
        });
```

Not sure this is the best way to create CacheManager. How do I implement a callback function to re-populate CacheEntry if it becomes null?

Comment: does your last block code register even work ? AFAIK, it just create an singleton instance of `CacheManager` from separate scope, would return a standalone instance of `DbContext`, but that `DbContext` would now became a singleton, too. Which should lead to various issues on scope process and change tracking as long as you keep using it (Personally I think it should throw out many exceptions after a while after deployed)

Comment: why would it return singleton DBContext? `scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<ILookupService>()` line should return scoped instance. By default in Web App, EF will register scoped instance of DBContext

Comment: The factory method only invoked once as initialized of `CacheManager` instance, therefore, only one `lookupService` instance was created to help `CacheManager` load data for the first time. Then what's  the difference here anyway ? Or if your intention since beginning was just make use of `lookupService` for initial data for `CacheManager` then it should be fine. I was though `CacheManager` make use of `ILookupService` as dependency. I might miss-understood something already

Comment: Yes, The lookup service is used to load data into Cache from the database on application start. We cannot inject ILookupService as dependency in CacheManager.  DI framework will throw error as `Singleton Cannot consume scoped service`. I want to know if CacheManager is Singleton,  what's the proper way to re-populate CacheEntry when it  becomes null

Comment: The usual way of a longer lived service to access a shorter lived service through DI is to inject a factory that creates the shorter lived services as needed. Is that not possible in your case?

Comment: CacheManager is depend on only `LookupService`, so implementing a factory to create a instance of one type adds unnecessary complexity

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the underlying issue is that ILookupService cannot be resolved until runtime and requests start coming in. You need to create CacheManager before this.

**DI COMPOSITION**

This should be done when the app starts - as in [this class of mine](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.apisample.netcore/blob/master/src/plumbing/dependencies/BaseCompositionRoot.cs#L145). Note the different lifetimes for different types of object but I just focus on creating the objects rather than interactions.

**DI RESOLUTION**

.Net uses a container per request pattern where scoped objects are stored against the HttpRequest object. So a singleton basically needs to ask for the current ILookupService, which is done by calling:

```cs
container.GetService<ILookupService>
```

So include the DI container as a constructor argument to your CacheManager class and you will be all set up. This is the service locator pattern and is needed to meet your requirement.

An alternative per request resolution mechanism is via the HttpContext object as in [this class](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.apisample.netcore/blob/master/src/plumbing/security/CustomAuthenticationHandler.cs#L33), where the following code is used:

```cs
IAuthorizer authorizer = (IAuthorizer)this.Context.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(IAuthorizer));
```

**SUMMARY**

The important thing is to understand the above design pattern, and you can then apply it to any technology.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I would simply configure services.AddSingleton<CacheManager>();
(CacheManager having a default constructor)

After configuring all of the DI dependencies and having a serviceprovider, get the Cachemanager singleton and initialize it with LoadCache.
(so let DI create "empty" singleton cachemanager, but initialize immediately somewhere in startup of application)

```
var cachemanager = scope.ServiceProvider.Get<CacheManager>();
var lookupService = scope.ServiceProvider.Get<ILookupService>();
var cache = scope.ServiceProvider.Get<IMemoryCache>();
cachemanager.Cache = cache;
cachemanager.LoadCache(lookupService.GetData());
```

Answer (score -1):

register Cache service as singleton, try below code

```
 public class CacheService : ICacheService
    {
        private ObjectCache _memoryCache;

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="CacheService"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        public CacheService()
        {
            this._memoryCache = System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache.Default;
        }
}
```